# How to use variables value while sourcing a file in Python script

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. I want to source the file which has a variable value. I am sourcing the variable value using command line argument option. I want to use this variable as a path parameter to source my file. I am saying it to the variable. Below is the code I am trying.

```
folder_name = 'abc'

execfile("/a/b/c/folder_name")
```

and I am expecting it will take the value of `folder_name` as abc and execute the file as

```
execfile("/a/b/c/abc")
```

Comment: Try `execfile("/a/b/c/{}".format(folder_name))`

Comment: Thanks Maroun, its worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done either with string concatenation, or with `format` - the latter being safer/better:

```
execfile("/a/b/c/" + folder_name)

execfile("/a/b/c/{}".format(folder_name)
```

For more info on `format`, see [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/)

However you might want to consider if `execfile` is the right approach here! Other data formats can be a better option - e.g. `pickle`, `json` or `yaml`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.format()` whenever you need to  insert variable name into string:

```
execfile("/a/b/c/{0}".format(folder_name))
```

Note that `{0}` here corresponds to first argument that you pass to `format` function.

Similarly, `{1}`, `{2}`,... corresponds to second, third,.. arguments of `format` function respectively.

You could also use `%` operator, but note that it is deprecated as of Python 3.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, I can use multiple variables in the same exec comamnd.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you are a beginner in Python then you should change your approach and should not use `execfile`

Instead consider using `pickle` or `json.load` to store data

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
folder_name = 'abc'

execfile("/a/b/c/{folder_name}".format(folder_name=folder_name))
```